# Drawing a ring around a torus (doughnut) using TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, 3d

I was trying to draw a 2-torus (a doughnut) using `TikZ`, based on the answer to my previous question [Moebius Strip using Tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118563/moebius-strip-using-tikz), and got the following
[image]

The result is impressive! However, the vertical circle does not look as surrounding the torus.

**Q:**

How could I give the right perspective of 3D?

**MWE**

WARNING: main tex-memory of my computer has been enhanced to compite this code

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,units}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      hide axis,
      view={60}{60}
    ]
    \addplot3 [
      surf, shader=interp,
      point meta=x,
      colormap/greenyellow,
      samples=40,
      samples y=40,
      z buffer=sort,
      domain=0:360,
      y domain=0:360
    ] (
              {(3.5 + 0.5*cos(y))*cos(x)},
              {(3.5 + 0.5*cos(y))*sin(x)},
              {0.5*sin(y)});
    \addplot3 [
     samples=40,
     domain=0:360,
     thick
    ] (
              {(3.5 + 0.5*cos(80))*cos(x)},
              {(3.5 + 0.5*cos(80))*sin(x)},
              {0.5*sin(80)});
    \addplot3 [
      samples=40,
      domain=0:360,
      thick
    ] (
              {3.5 + 0.5*cos(x)},
              {0},
              {0.5*sin(x)});

  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm marking this question as duplicate, see: [solution 1](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348/how-to-draw-a-torus), [solution 2](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70090/3d-helix-torus-with-hidden-lines). Alternatively using pst-solides3d: [solution 3](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27597/drawing-checkered-torus-doughnut)

Comment: @juliohm None of the post you pointed out are solutions to my problem! And I checked them previously to post mine. The closest answer uses something called `sketch` and it's not explained how to use the `sketch` command. The other use postscript... which are not usable for my purposes. However, I thank your concern.

Comment: @juliohm: To vote for closing a question as a duplicate, you have to click the `close` link underneath the question (I think you might not have enough reputation to see it, though). However, I don't think this is a duplicate, since the answers to your first link don't show how to draw a circle around the torus (Dox has the torus part in his question, he was specifically asking about the circle), and the second link is concerned with a much more complicated drawing that requires a different approach.

Comment: @juliohm: Ah, I see that you can flag to close instead of directly voting. Anyway, my above comment is my explanation why I disagreed with your close flag in the flag review.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You'll have to manually adjust the domain over which the circle is evaluated, so that it's only drawn on the visible side:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,units}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      hide axis,
      view={60}{30},
      axis equal image,
    ]
    \addplot3 [
      surf, shader=interp,
      point meta=x,
      colormap/greenyellow,
      samples=40,
      samples y=20,
      z buffer=sort,
      domain=0:360,
      y domain=0:360
    ] (
              {(3.5 + 0.5*cos(y))*cos(x)},
              {(3.5 + 0.5*cos(y))*sin(x)},
              {0.5*sin(y)});
    \addplot3 [
     samples=40,
     samples y=1,
     domain=0:360,
     thick
    ] (
              {(3.5 + 0.5*cos(80))*cos(x)},
              {(3.5 + 0.5*cos(80))*sin(x)},
              {0.5*sin(80)});
    \addplot3 [
      samples=10,
      samples y=1,
      domain=-65:130,
      thick
    ] (
              {3.5 + 0.5*cos(x)},
              {0},
              {0.5*sin(x)});

  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @jake! Once more, you've saved the day! Cheers.