# Logo hexagon in the form of a ribbon

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

I wish to make a logo like the one in http://math.et.info.free.fr/TikZ/aideLogoSite.html.

But with a hexagon pattern as in the attached picture. It has no text, and it is better with two options: one had shadow, the other with curves, lines only making a negative space effect. Simple is best so that it can be used with pdflatex.

How can I make one with Tikz?

[image]

Comment: I think questions on Moebius strips might be relevant to search for.  For example, Gonzalo's answer at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118563/moebius-strip-using-tikz is similar.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes They are from the same source :)

Comment: @percusse I had not noted that.

Comment: @percusse: That was me. +3 for [tag:do-this-for-me] and no research effort.

Comment: @Werner The code is in the link.

Comment: @Werner Who was you? I guess it should be `+3 for do-this-for-me and almost no research effort` for the sake of accuracy?

Comment: Coudl you help to modify this to make a mobius in the shape of triangle insteaad of hexagon?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Once we see that these Mobius ribbons always have a regular polygon in the middle the rest is practically finding a nice curve over each edge such that it blends with the next edge nicely (see the hexagon in the middle).

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\tikzset{my polygon/.style={regular polygon,regular polygon sides=#1,minimum size=4cm}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[top color=black!50!blue,bottom color=blue]
\node[my polygon=6] (a){};
\foreach \x[remember=\x as \xp (initially 6)] in {1,...,6}{ % use `in {1}` to see the edge
  \fill[shade,shading angle={60*(\x+2)}] (a.corner \xp)
     ..controls ++(60*\x:2cm) .. 
     ([shift={({60*(\x+1)+6}:1.5cm)}]a.corner \x) 
     -- (a.corner \x);% Come back such that shading doesn't leak
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

When we remove the fill, all my lies reveal themselves and we need further tweaks(I've also forgot the `outer sep=0` before). Because we have to know the tangent point on the next bezier curve. I don't see any immediate fix for that since we are trying to blend in to a curve that is not drawn yet. Hence this :

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,calc}
\tikzset{my polygon/.style={regular polygon,regular polygon sides=#1,minimum size=4cm}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[my polygon=6,draw,outer sep=0] (a){};
\foreach \x[remember=\x as \xp (initially 6)] in {1,...,6}{
\draw[] (a.corner \xp)
      ..controls ++(60*\x:2cm) ..
        ([shift={({60*(\x+1)+7.35}:1.55cm)}]a.corner \x); % This part needs tweaking for a 
                                                       % nice blend (or a derivative I think).
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You could try to emulate the pink color from the image, which looks nice :P

Comment: @Manuel I would if I wasn't colorblind and didn't think that it was one of those *strange* colors.

Comment: Ahm, I did not know :)

Comment: The blue is much nicer than the pink anyway.

Comment: Thank you. It looks awesome online yet the shadow effect disappear when printed on paper. How can we make the simplified one with just curves and lines, still having the negative space effect?

Comment: @Thumbolt Add `draw` option to node `(a)` and start the next command with `\filldraw[draw=black,fill=white]` for example.

Comment: I could not draw it as lines and curves as in UKMT logo which is good for printing and 3D viewing. Could you please help.

Comment: \begin{tikzpicture}[top color=black!50!blue,bottom color=blue]
\node[my polygon=6, draw] (a){};
\foreach \x[remember=\x as \xp (initially 6)] in {1,...,6}{ % use `in {1}` to see the edge
  \filldraw[draw=black,fill=white, shade,shading angle={60*(\x+2)}] (a.corner \xp)
     ..controls ++(60*\x:2cm) .. 
     ([shift={({60*(\x+1)+6}:1.5cm)}]a.corner \x) 
     -- (a.corner \x);% Come back such that shading doesn't leak
}
\end{tikzpicture}

Comment: @Thumbolt Instead of this, add `draw` to the node options and then replace the path in the loop with `\draw[] (a.corner \xp)..controls ++(60*\x:2cm) ..([shift={({60*(\x+1)+6}:1.5cm)}]a.corner \x);`

Comment: It works now, but the sides of inner hexagon do not coincide with the other lines with a closer look. How can we increase the side length of this hexagon? I change the number 2cm and 1.5cm slightly but it is not helpful. By the way, I would use this logo for my project and I would like to write your name for the credit of making this possible.

Comment: @Thumbolt I've added another version. It is not that automatic as I tweaked my way out. But you can also do the same. The size is the `minimum size` key. And regarding the license, that's very kind of you but you don't need to do anything, look at my profile for the license I use ;)

Comment: Perfect now. May I know your full name and affiliation?

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}    
\draw[rounded corners=6mm, ultra thick]
  (3.97, 5.91) -- (6.15,3.65) -- (5.28,0.64) --
  (2.24,-0.12) -- (0.06,2.14) -- (0.93,5.15) --
  cycle;    
\draw [thick] (4.23,4.2) -- (1.14,5.1);    
\draw [thick] (2.53,4.53) -- (0.217,2.25);    
\draw [thick] (2.04,1.57) -- (5.09,0.69);    
\draw [thick] (3.74,1.34) -- (6,3.52);    
\draw [thick] (4.77,2.71) -- (4.02,5.7);    
\draw [thick] (1.42,3.17) -- (2.18,0.1);    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

The [wheelchart](https://ctan.org/pkg/wheelchart) package, which I wrote, can be used.

The inner part of the slices is a straight line segment by using the key `slices inner arc={0}{0}`.

Using the key `slices outer angle shift`, the end angle and the start angle of the outer part of the slices is modified.

The outer part of the slices is determined by the key `slices outer to={45}{10}`. This key sets the `to` path operation for the outer part of the slices. The angle at the start is `45` and the angle at the end is `10`.

The shading is defined in the key `slices style`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{wheelchart}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[looseness=0.5]
\wheelchart[
  slices inner arc={0}{0},
  slices outer angle shift=90-180/\WCtotalcount,
  slices outer to={45}{10},
  slices style={
    left color=pink,
    right color=pink!20!white,
    shading angle=\WCmidangle
  },
  start angle=0,
  total count=6
]{}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```