# Welcoming 2019 Lunar New Year: How to draw a (lovely) pig?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, asymptote, fun, tikzlings

[Chinese Zodiac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_zodiac) and [Lunar Year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_calendar) can be called very close friends. In Eastern cultures, each lunar year is assigned to one of the twelve animals in Chinese zodiac. The animal (or rather a mascot) of this year is the pig. So, my question in this question is:

> **How to draw a (lovely) pig in LaTeX?**

I found a very beautiful picture on TeXample:

[image]

```
% Author M.R.C. van Dongen
% Draw parameterised pig.
% This code can/should be improved by using the pgfkey library.

\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{keyval}

\makeatletter

% We're not using pgfkeys, and we've chosen to use keyval
% for option parsing. The following define the keys for a
% pig keyval family. The main purpose of the keys and
% default values is that we want to be able to draw pigs
% with predefined colours for certain parts and predefined
% scaling factors for line thickness.

\def\pig@draw@thick@width{0.85}
\def\pig@draw@thin@width{0.20}
\def\pig@label{pig label}
\tikzset{draw thick/.style={draw=black,line width=0.85}}
\tikzset{draw thin/.style={draw=black,line width=0.20}}
\tikzset{fill colour/.style={fill=pink}}
\tikzset{nose hole fill colour/.style={fill=purple!50!gray}}
\tikzset{eye fill colour/.style={fill=white}}
\tikzset{pupil fill colour/.style={fill=black}}

\define@key{pig}{draw thick}{\def\draw@pig@thick@width{#1}}
\define@key{pig}{draw thin}{\def\draw@pig@thin@width{#1}}
\define@key{pig}{fill colour}{\tikzset{fill colour/.style={fill=#1}}}
\define@key{pig}{nose hole fill colour}{\tikzset{nose hole fill colour/.style={fill=#1}}}
\define@key{pig}{eye fill colour}{\tikzset{eye fill colour/.style={fill=#1}}}
\define@key{pig}{pupil fill colour}{\tikzset{pupil fill colour/.style={fill=#1}}}
\define@key{pig}{pig label}{\def\pig@label{#1}}
\def\pig@scale{1}

\def\pig{\@ifnextchar[\draw@pig{\draw@pig[]}}
\def\draw@pig[#1]#2{%
   % Set the relative line width for thick lines.
   \def\draw@pig@thick@width{0.85}
   % Set the relative line width for thin lines.
   \def\draw@pig@thin@width{0.20}
   % Set the relative scale of the pig.
   \def\pig@scale{#2}
   \setkeys{pig}{#1}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=#2,
                       draw thick/.style={draw=black,line width=\draw@pig@thick@width*\pig@scale},
                       draw thin/.style={draw=black,line width=\draw@pig@thin@width*\pig@scale}]
   \path (0,0)            coordinate (\pig@label head)
         + (-0.005,-0.20) coordinate (\pig@label nose)
         + (-0.010,+0.05) coordinate (\pig@label body)
         + (-0.010,+0.45) coordinate (\pig@label tail);
   % Define points for tail.
   \foreach \number/\point in {1/{+0.000,+0.055},%
                               2/{-0.058,+0.075},%
                               3/{+0.044,+0.094},%
                               4/{-0.072,+0.137},%
                               5/{+0.048,+0.170},%
                               6/{-0.078,+0.206}} {
       \path (\pig@label tail) +(\point) coordinate (tail \number);
   }
   % Define points for ears and legs.
   \foreach \offset in {-1,1} {
       \path (\pig@label head)
                    ++ (+0.12*\offset,+0.00) coordinate (ear pt 1 \offset)
                    +  (-0.04*\offset,+0.07) coordinate (ear pt 2 \offset)
                    +  (-0.02*\offset,+0.25) coordinate (ear pt 3 \offset)
                    +  (+0.11*\offset,+0.25) coordinate (ear pt 4 \offset)
                    +  (+0.14*\offset,+0.13) coordinate (ear pt 5 \offset)
                    +  (+0.09*\offset,-0.06) coordinate (ear pt 6 \offset)
             (\pig@label head)
                    ++ (+0.09*\offset,-0.30) coordinate (leg 1 \offset)
                    ++ (+0.01*\offset,-0.24) coordinate (leg 2 \offset)
                    ++ (+0.04*\offset,+0.08) coordinate (leg 3 \offset)
                    ++ (+0.04*\offset,-0.08) coordinate (leg 4 \offset)
                    ++ (+0.02*\offset,+0.30) coordinate (leg 5 \offset);
   }
   % draw legs.
   \foreach \number in {-1,1} {
      \filldraw[fill colour,draw thick]
         (leg 1 \number) --
         (leg 2 \number) --
         (leg 3 \number) --
         (leg 4 \number) --
         (leg 5 \number) -- cycle;
   }
   % draw tail.
   \draw[draw thick,line join=round,line cap=round]
         (\pig@label tail) \foreach \num in {1,...,6} { -- (tail \num)};
   % draw body.
   \draw[fill colour,draw thick]
         (\pig@label body) ellipse (4.50mm and 4.10mm);
   % draw ears.
   \foreach \number in {-1,1} {
      % ears
      \filldraw[fill colour,draw thick]
         (ear pt 1 \number) .. controls
         (ear pt 2 \number) and
         (ear pt 3 \number) ..
         (ear pt 4 \number) .. controls
         (ear pt 5 \number) and
         (ear pt 6 \number) .. (ear pt 1 \number);
   }
   % draw nose.
   \filldraw[fill colour,draw thick]
         (\pig@label head) ellipse (1.42mm and 1.40mm);
   \foreach \offset in {-1,1} {
       \filldraw[draw thin,eye fill colour]
                (\pig@label head) ++ (-0.006,0.00) ++ (0.055*\offset,+0.03)
                coordinate (eye \offset)
                ellipse (0.04 and 0.060);
       \fill[pupil fill colour]
            (eye \offset) ellipse (0.020 and 0.035);
   }
   \filldraw[fill colour,draw thick]
         (\pig@label nose) ellipse (2.60mm and 1.72mm);
   % Draw nose holes
   \foreach \offset in {-1,1} {
       \filldraw[draw thick,nose hole fill colour]
                (\pig@label nose) ++ (\offset*0.080,0)
                 ellipse (0.50mm and 0.85mm);
   }
   \end{tikzpicture}
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw (0,0) node[anchor=south]{\pig{3}}
         (4,0) node[anchor=south]{\pig[nose hole fill colour=purple!20,fill colour=blue!40]{5}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However, I wish to see more pigs here, especially with other familiar animals, like [lions, ducks,](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8011/156344) <strike>marmots</strike>[, bears, rabbits, birds, donkeys, or penguins](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8011/156344).

I am also looking for a [`tikzlings`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikzlings?lang=en) pig!

Comment: may is it a good idea to include the code with proper citations just for archiving purposes?

Comment: `Package inputenc Error: Unicode character  (U+1F416)(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX. ` :(

Comment: @Sanchises use xelatex or lualatex (and a suitable font)  then post an answer:)

Comment: Marmots are not animals! We are beings! ;-)

Comment: We also need ASCII pig contest on CodeGolf. :)

Comment: @val something like `\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ducksay}

\begin{document}

\ducksay[animal=pig]{Hi!}

\end{document}`?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The very first appearance of the `tikzpig`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{piglight}{RGB}{246,208,198}
\definecolor{pigdark}{RGB}{241,164,142}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

% Tail %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\draw[pigdark,thick] (0.8471, 0.5927) .. controls (0.8549, 0.4832) and (0.8046, 0.4105) .. (0.7319, 0.4079) .. controls (0.6592, 0.4052) and (0.6142, 0.4365) .. (0.5964, 0.5024) .. controls (0.5786, 0.5682) and (0.6252, 0.6291) .. (0.6794, 0.6342) .. controls (0.7335, 0.6394) and (0.7561, 0.6114) .. (0.7663, 0.5661) .. controls (0.7765, 0.5208) and (0.746, 0.458) .. (0.7192, 0.4319) .. controls (0.6924, 0.4058) and (0.7073, 0.4182) .. (0.6604, 0.3859) .. controls (0.6134, 0.3536) and (0.4367, 0.3643) .. (0.3877, 0.5055);

% Body %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\fill[piglight] ( 0.6,  0.8 ) .. controls ( 0.6 , 0.4) and ( 0.35, 0.16) .. ( 0.0,  0.16) .. controls (-0.35, 0.16) and (-0.6 , 0.4) .. (-0.6,  0.8 ) .. controls (-0.6 , 1.3) and (-0.35, 1.5) .. ( 0.0,  1.5) .. controls ( 0.35, 1.5) and ( 0.6 , 1.3) .. ( 0.6,  0.75) -- cycle;

% Arms %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\fill[pigdark,rotate around={70:(0.33,0.9)}] (0.33,0.9) ellipse (0.18 and 0.13);
\fill[pigdark,rotate around={-70:(-0.33,0.9)}] (-0.33,0.9) ellipse (0.18 and 0.13);

% Head %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\fill[piglight] (0,1.64) ellipse (.5 and .5);

% Eyes %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\fill[gray] (-0.09, 1.82) circle (0.02);
\fill[gray] ( 0.09, 1.82) circle (0.02);

% Nose %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\fill[pigdark]  (0, 1.62) ellipse (0.18 and 0.14);
\fill[gray]  (-0.06, 1.62) circle (0.035);
\fill[gray]  ( 0.06, 1.62) circle (0.035);

% Mouth %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\draw[gray] (0.105, 1.46) arc [start angle=-50, end angle=-130, radius=0.16] ;

% Ears %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\fill[pigdark] (0.22, 2.0392) .. controls   (0.22, 2.1584) and  (0.49460, 2.255) ..     (0.49460, 2.255) .. controls    (0.49460, 2.255) and (0.5300, 1.86) .. (0.3721, 1.86) .. controls (0.2891, 1.86) and    (0.22, 1.9201) .. (0.22, 2.0392) -- cycle;
\fill[piglight] (0.22, 2.0392) .. controls (0.26, 2.1584) and (0.47, 2.22) .. (0.47, 2.20) .. controls (0.47, 2.2) and (0.49, 1.9) .. (0.3721, 1.9) .. controls (0.2891, 1.88) and (0.22, 1.88) .. (0.22, 2.0392) -- cycle; 
\fill[pigdark] (-0.22, 2.0392) .. controls  (-0.22, 2.1584) and     (-0.49460, 2.255) ..    (-0.49460, 2.255) .. controls   (-0.49460, 2.255) and (-0.5300, 1.86) .. (-0.3721, 1.86) .. controls (-0.2891, 1.86) and    (-0.22, 1.9201) .. (-0.22, 2.0392) -- cycle;
\fill[piglight] (-0.22, 2.0392) .. controls (-0.26, 2.1584) and (-0.47, 2.22) .. (-0.47, 2.20) .. controls (-0.47, 2.2) and (-0.49, 1.9) .. (-0.3721, 1.9) .. controls (-0.2891, 1.88) and (-0.22, 1.88) .. (-0.22, 2.0392) -- cycle;   

% Feet %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{scope}
    \clip (-0.5,0.4) rectangle (0.5,0.13);
    \fill[pigdark] (-0.22,0.17) circle (0.15);
    \fill[pigdark] (0.22,0.17) circle (0.15);
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

In the mean time, the `tikzpig` was added to the development version of the `tikzlings` package (available [here](https://github.com/samcarter/tikzlings)) with improvements by [@Circumscribe](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/156366/circumscribe) and [@CarLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/101651/carlatex) (thanks a lot!)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikzlings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pig
\end{tikzpicture}   

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @KJO I trust in the cuteness of tikzlings :)

Comment: @Circumscribe The smaller hat looks indeed much better! Thanks for the suggestion! (I'll have to adjust some sizes anyway to make it compatible with all the hats etc. from the tikzlings package, I will upload a new version, once this is done)

Comment: @Circumscribe Oh, posting a link to the code was actually much better than just an image, so I could just copy and paste what I needed. I also notoced that you replaced the head with a circle: you really live up to your user name :) Thanks again for your suggestions!

Comment: Looks awesome: some extra chubbiness is appropriate and I like the feet. (I tried to cover up the circle thing by calling it an ellipse, but you clearly didn't fall for it :).)

Comment: @Circumscribe Credit for the new feet goes to @ CarLaTeX :)

Comment: @KJO I don't need multiple accounts, there are enough tikzlings out there :)

Comment: @KJO Oh, what an exciting competition! The tikz rebellion against the picture mode empire!

Comment: @KJO and his picpig probably calls the picducks to help: https://github.com/samcarter/picducks

Comment: my hearing is going did you say pigducks ? is there a duck snout accessory ? ooh

Comment: @KJO Naaah, I said picduck. You must be thinking about pigducks, which look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhALd.png

Comment: Thanks that's been fun, but need to get back to work for a bit, Been reminded to reduce chat(err) thanks for the fun will sit and watch quietly as this plays out

Comment: @KJO Was fun for me too :) Have fun at work!

Comment: I _do_ expect a `\pig` in the next version of `tikzlings`! Amazing!

Comment: @JouleV Already in the dev version: https://github.com/samcarter/tikzlings/commit/dc69a0d2cd2f28e181ca3d34fd406bfc1d31bd4e

Comment: @Circumscribe Thanks a lot for this nice suggestion! I'll update the code tonight.

Comment: @samcarter shall we call them `piglings` ?

Answer (score 68):

You really don't need any packages for this

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{picture}(100,100)

\put(43,56){\circle{6}}
\put(43,56){\circle*{1}}
\put(57,56){\circle{6}}
\put(57,56){\circle*{1}}
\put(50,45){\circle{12}}
\put(48,45){\oval(3,5)}
\put(52,45){\oval(3,5)}
\put(50,50){\circle{40}}
\put(43,32){\oval(5,20)[b]}
\put(57,32){\oval(5,20)[b]}
\put(64,64){\vector(1,1){10}}
\end{picture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could be more accurate by rotating the footpads 180 makes them look like trotters :-) but you got my +1

Comment: YOU SIR ARE A LEGEND!

Comment: Can the coordinates be expressed in `ex` units? I tried but received some errors.

Comment: @bp2017 the coordinates are multiples of `\unitlength` so `\setlength\unitlength{1em}` before the environment.

Answer (score 45):

For the sake of completeness, let's go for a Unicode pig!

```
% arara: xelatex
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setmainfont{Symbola}

\begin{document}
\scalebox{10}{\char"1F416}
\end{document}
```

[image: Pig]

Comment: and Sanchises could have posted his first answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/473287/welcoming-2019-lunar-new-year-how-to-draw-a-lovely-pig/473428?noredirect=1#comment1193634_473287

Comment: I didn't notice the comment. `:)` Yet, a font lookup was needed anyway...

Comment: Thumb up if you eat pork!

Answer (score 29):

Another pig... wrapped in [percusse's incredible ribbon](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/236228/121799).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,3d}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} % tikzpigture doesn't work
 \path[ball color=pink,opacity=0.5,postaction={fill=pink}] (0,0.2) circle (2cm);
 \path[ball color=pink,opacity=0.5,postaction={fill=pink}] (0,0) circle (1.3cm);
 \tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{0}
 \begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords,smooth]
  \path[top color=pink!70,bottom color=pink,shading angle=25] 
  plot[variable=\t,domain=0:180] ({0.6*cos(\t)},0.5,{0.6*sin(\t)-0.3})
  -- plot[variable=\t,domain=180:0] ({0.6*cos(\t)},0,{0.6*sin(\t)-0.3});
  \fill[pink]
  plot[variable=\t,domain=0:360] ({0.6*cos(\t)},0,{0.6*sin(\t)-0.3});
  \fill plot[variable=\t,domain=0:360]({0.3+0.15*cos(\t)},0,{0.15*sin(\t)});
  \fill plot[variable=\t,domain=0:360]({-0.3+0.15*cos(\t)},0,{0.15*sin(\t)});
  \fill plot[variable=\t,domain=0:180]({0.35*cos(\t)},0,{-0.3-0.15*sin(\t)})
  plot[variable=\t,domain=180:0]({0.35*cos(\t)},0,{-0.3-0.35*sin(\t)});
  \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{-20}{30}{00}
  \begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords] % right eaw
   \path[inner color=black,outer color=pink] plot[variable=\t,domain=80:170]
   ({0.53*cos(\t)},{0.53*sin(\t)},{1.2})
    -- plot[variable=\t,domain=170:80]
    ({0.53*cos(\t)},{0.53*sin(\t)},{1.2+0.4*sin((170-\t)*2)});
  \end{scope} 
  \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{20}{-30}{00}
  \begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords] % left eaw
   \path[inner color=black,outer color=pink] plot[variable=\t,domain=10:100]
   ({0.53*cos(\t)},{0.53*sin(\t)},{1.2})
    -- plot[variable=\t,domain=100:10]
    ({0.53*cos(\t)},{0.53*sin(\t)},{1.2+0.4*sin((100-\t)*2)});
  \end{scope} 
  \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{-30}{40}{0}
  \begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords] % right eye
   \fill plot[variable=\t,domain=0:360]({0.2*cos(\t)},{0.2*sin(\t)},{1.3});
  \end{scope} 
  \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{30}{-40}{0}
  \begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords] % left eye
   \fill plot[variable=\t,domain=0:360]({0.2*cos(\t)},{0.2*sin(\t)},{1.3});
  \end{scope}
  \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{20}{-150}{0}
  \begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords]
   \path[ball color=pink,postaction={fill=pink}] 
    plot[variable=\t,domain=0:180] ({0.4*cos(\t)},{0.4*sin(\t)},1.8)
  -- plot[variable=\t,domain=180:0] ({0.4*cos(\t)},{0.4*sin(\t)},2.4);
   \path[ball color=black,rotate around={-10:(0,0,2.35)}] (0,0,2.35) circle(4mm and 2mm);
  \end{scope}
  \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{-20}{150}{0}
  \begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords]
   \path[ball color=pink,postaction={fill=pink}] 
    plot[variable=\t,domain=0:180] ({0.4*cos(\t)},{0.4*sin(\t)},1.8)
  -- plot[variable=\t,domain=180:0] ({0.4*cos(\t)},{0.4*sin(\t)},2.4);
   \path[ball color=black,rotate around={10:(0,0,2.35)}] (0,0,2.35) circle(4mm and 2mm);
  \end{scope}
 \end{scope}
 \begin{scope}[my polygon/.style={regular polygon,regular polygon
  sides=#1,minimum size=6cm},
  Moebigon/.pic={ % based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/236228/121799
\node[my polygon=#1] (a){};
\foreach \x[remember=\x as \xp (initially #1)] in {1,...,#1}{ % use `in {1}` to see the edge
  \fill[shade,shading angle={360*(\x+2)/#1}] (a.corner \xp)
     ..controls ++(360*\x/#1:2cm) .. 
     ([shift={({360*(\x+1)/#1+12-#1}:1.5cm)}]a.corner \x) 
     -- (a.corner \x);% Come back such that shading doesn't leak
}
},top color=black!50!red,bottom color=red]  
   \pic {Moebigon=6}; 
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I bet its 3D and is that a Micrometer sleeve at the front ?

Comment: @KJO No, it is not. I would actually be considerable effort to make it 3d. There are some elements that are in principle, though.... (the eyes and the nose)

Comment: Apart from David does not know how to plot curly line all the others have tails~

Comment: @KJO In this sense it is 3D: the tail is hidden by the body. ;-)

Comment: Thought that would be your answer :-)

Comment: @KJO oi! I could have use `\qbezier` but I didn't want to spoil the elegance of the `\vector` implementation, which benefits from simplicity of markup and almost photographic realism. Unlike a certain 3D package I could mention which makes things looking like balloon animals made by a children's entertainer.

Comment: How cute!!!!!!!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Please note I was one of your earlier upvoters as I acknowledge your TeX graphic skills Greatly surpasses my own  (and I get paid to draw :-)  Marmot, SamCarter et Al know I admire their abilities in making it "look" so easy" and even Paulo out-beat me as my Unicode pigs got pilloried. Most of my suggestions are leg-pulling However am impressed how my irony  falls "like water of a ducks back" and the results usually exceed my and OP's expectations.

Comment: @KJO my reply was to be taken in the same spirit:-)  (apart from the part saying marmot's attempt looks like a twisted balloon, of course)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Aw that's cruel, I was taught one should not pick on the smaller ones, just educate them

Comment: @marmot Just one thing is missing: `animations`.

Comment: @Raaja This is a very very slow animation. ;-)

Comment: @marmot I can see the animation via my time wrapper :)

Comment: Can I rotate it 180 if I turn the monitor towards the wall ¿ and then see the çurly tail ç>°-° ¿

Comment: @KJO My laptop has also an outer screen, on which you can see the tail. All you need to do is to buy such a laptop. ;-)

Comment: @KJO Can't promise. (Are these real or virtual screens?)

Comment: @KJO Makes sense. (I guess drawing a 3d pig with Ti*k*Z will be a bit cumbersome. Drawing 2 3d spheres that intersect and can be rotated at will could be feasible with reasonably little effort, I did however not try.)

Comment: is it one of these https://www.techradar.com/uk/news/asus-dual-screen-laptop-rocks-intel-core-i9-power-with-discrete-graphics I don't think it can look round corners though one of mine is transformable so I could try flipping it off the desk !

Comment: @KJO No, those do not have marmot-friendly keyboards. ;-)

Answer (score 27):

run with `xelatex`

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-fun}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-2,-4)(8,4)
  \psPig(0,0)
  \psPig[fillcolor=blue!40,noseColor=purple,eyeColor=red,linewidth=4pt,unit=2](4,0)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Though I am very late for the fun, I haven't seen an `ascii` contribution yet. Hence, here is my contribution in the form of `ascii` art `:)`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents,listings,graphicx,varwidth}

\begin{filecontents*}{pig.txt}
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWMWWWMMMMMMMMMMMWWWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWWWWNXK0OOkkxxdddoolooooollccc:::;;;;,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,;;;;::::cccccclllooddoc:::cllodxO0KXNWWWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWWNX0Oxdlc;,'....                                                          ....        .....''',,,,;:cloxk0XNWWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWWNKOxol:,'..                                                                     .:dO0OOOkkxkOKKXXXXXXXXK0Okkdl:::;;:ldk0XWWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWNKOxxol:,..                         ..,;:'  .;:coxOkdl,..,:cll;.  ...    ..;coddoclodoo;..;kXWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMN0kdddolcllcldkKNWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWXkl,.           .;cc;.  .,. .':ldxdc:cx0KKKX0kOXNN0xoc:codkOOxooxxddollclkOOkOXNXXXXKkc;:lolodOKKKNWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWXKK0OOOOkxdddoolloxOXWWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWKo.           .;odddoll:';xOxodx0K0KXXNWWWWNXWMMMXOxc;cx0XNKxdooxOkoxOOOOKNWMWNXXWNKK0OOOOKNWWWWNXKXNNXWMMMMWXXWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWXK0OOkkkxxol:;;ldOXWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWWNNNWWMMMMMMMMMMXd'       ...'lxOOkxxk0XWWXK00OO0KXWMMWX00KNMMMWXOkkOKXNWNKOxxxxOOOOxoKNKOkk0XXKKXNWNXXX0OOKNMWNXOxkKWMWNWMMMMMNNWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWX0Okkkxdl;...;lkKNWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNkl;'',:ldk0XWMMMWO;       ,dK00XXKKKXWNKKWMMMWNNWMMMMMMWNXXNXXX0kdxkO0KNNK0OOOKXXKXWNX0xdxkOOkxk0KNWNKkdloxOXWMNK000XWMMMMMWNWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMN0O0O0K0o'   .,cd0XWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMXx;.. ..     ..;lxx:.      ,d0NWMMWXWMWKOk0XWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWXOxxkkkOKK0l;ckOO0XNNWMMN0o::ldO0Ododk0Oxolc:cdkO00KWMWNNNNXNWNXNWNXNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNKKNMWWWW0c.     ..:oOXWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNk;.:xkO00k;               .o0X0OKX0OKXOkkKNMMMMWNWNOkONMMWXkc;cOXXKKK000kxO000XWMWXkoc:cdOOdcclkK0kxxxdoxxdlcd0NWNX0kxxxk0NNNWWNNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWX0OO0NWXKXKOo,.      .;o0NMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWNXK0OkxxxxxkkOOOO00KWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMXl. .ooxXNNN0o:,.          .oKNWXOxxxkkxOXWMMMWXOOkxddkKWN0l,,:x00OkkkOKXXKOxxOXNXkoccoO0Od;,:d0XKOkOKXKko::ldk0K0OkOOkkk0XXKXWMWNWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMN00KXNWXKXWWN0c.        .;dKNWWWWNNXXXKK0OOkxddoc:'...        ..''..,dXMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNo.     .,;;dXWWXl         ;kNMMWNKOkxk0NMMMMNOlcodxkKWWKx:,:dOOkkOKK0O0K0kdldKKOdodkKX0d;',oO00OOO0XWNKkddOXXK0kkkk00kdlldKWWWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMN0OXWMMNKKXXOoc:;,.        .,:::;,''......       ....... .;lodkOxc;o0NMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMXc          'OWW0;        ;0WN0kkOOkOKWMNXNNk;..:okXWNOo:cd0K0O0KNNK0K0kxxO00Oxox0NN0d;.'ckKKOxxKNXKXXkx0NWWXOdlccldolloxkKWMMMWWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWWMMMMMMNK00Odl;.                     ..;clooxxkkOOOdlcdKKK0kdokXWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWx.  'cc,.  .xNO,      .;d0NKkxk0O0NMMNOxxdo;';lkKNXklcd0KXXKXNXOkO0Oxdx0XKkddOXX0d;..;xKWXkoxOXWWXKK0O0XKxc;oOOdollld0NWWWX0Okk0WMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWXXWMMWKkkOOkkOxc'.                ..,cokKXXNNXK0OxdxOXXKOo;';lxKWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMK:  .:dd,  ;Ox'    .:xKNXOddxKNWWNXXkccoooOOkOKXKxloOXXKKX0oclok00kkOOKKOkxOKOdo;.,o0NXkocoOK0dc:lxO0Odc:cldxkxdxk0XX0kkkkkk0KNWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNKKNWMWNK00kdlc::,. .....     ..;ld0XK0OkkOKXWNXK00KXX0d;';lkKWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWO'   ;dc..::.  .;dOkKX0kxOKKOXMNOd:..:xK0kOKXOooxKKKKKKOc,;o0NNXK0Oxo;:xKOdoooddkXXOl::d0KOc. .lOOo;,:oxOOO0KK00KOl;lOKXNWMWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWNNMMMMMMMWKOKNNNKOxl. .;x00xdo; .:ldKNWX0kddxOXNNK00XWMWKd;.  .oKWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWk'          .:xxddOKOOO0XNKkKN0c;cldKKdoOKklokXKOOKKx:,lk0XWMN0kkkxdoxkkxxkOOKX0d::ok00Okl,,d00xccxKNXXXOdlcccoddoxXWWNK0KXWMNKXWWNNMMMMMMMMMMMWNNWMMMMMMMMMMMMNXNMMMMMWNNNNWWXXK0kdodxkd:'.;'  ;kOO0KK0OOkOOkKNXOxkXWKl.       .;coxxkOKXNWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWx.         .lxxxxxdx0KOkOkkK0; ,kXKkdxkd:ckXKOO00o,'l0X0OKWXx;,cox00kdxk0KNXkl:lxO00OkoclxOkxddkXWWXOo,..:oxkOOOOkdooox0NWWNXXNWWXNMMMMMMMMMMMWXXWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNKKKKXNX00K0xl,.  .,l,  ,cdO00kdddddkKNKOkOOkl.               ....,:ldO0XNMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMK:.;;.    'oxdxxdx0NXkkKX0kdlcdKKdcxOo,,d0xclxd:..lOOkkkk0XO:.;d0Ol,;lxOKKxllxkOOOkdc;cdkkxdxkOOOOkl..:d0KKOxo;'.,ck0XWWXOkkOKXNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWNXXWWXKNMMMNKOk0NN0dl:codxdkOk:    ,xxl',cdkO0XWNKOOxdl.          ..,:oxOOc.    .;o0WMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWKl'l0l.    ....;;,:kNX0OXWXkk0XXx::dl,'cdl;c;'. .lko;;dKX0d:,ck0x:.;okOOkxdxkkkkkxl::loxkxxxxddxxl::cd0NWKxc,.':okKWMMWKOdx0NWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWXO0NMMWMMMMMMMMMMWKkkkxxOKNWWx.    ..  .oxkXWMMMN0kl.           :x0XWWW0o;..':lx0XWWMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWXd,  .'          .;dkO0OkO0Ox0NK0d:xXOdd0Xxcoo, 'oKKo'c0XOl;;oOkl,'cdkkkkxxxxddxdl::oxxxkkxxoodxdl:;lkXNKxc,,cdO0xdkNMWWKxokXMMWXXXNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNXNWMMMMMWKOOOO00000x;. .lkOOkxxo'     .;:';odddo,.             'dOkxolllldOKNWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMXd'         .,...:dxxxxxkKWXOkO00OO0XX0OdoxKNNWXxdkl;;cx0x:;ckKk:.,okkxxxdddddxOk:,cdddxkkkxodxxdl:cxK0Od:,;oOKOd:,;xXXkollldONWX0OOKNMMMMMMMMMMMNKNMMMMMMMMMMMMWNKNMMMMMWN0kxkkOOkl,;;..,lkKNN0l.                                ..':okKNWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMWO;           .:oxkdodkKK000OOOkkOO0XKOkkkkk00xoOXOl;;lxkxddkKKOo:cxOxddd:,lkO0NXOdoollxO0OxddxxdooxKWNOl;:oO0kl;,;lddo:':dkOKNWMMMNK0KNMMMMMMMMMMMWNWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNKKKKKKK0000kdOKO00Oxdl:'                             ,oolox0XWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMWXo.       ..   :kd:..lXNXNXkdxOKNK00OkxxO0XNKOxddoodx0KkdxOX0dcclxKKOkkKXOxdkNMWX0OkolkXWXkdxxxxdxkdk0dlcokOdc;;lddoooll:lKWWXOxk0XXNNWMMMMNXXWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWWMMMWXNWNXKKKXNKOxxxxxxdllodxl.                  ...      .oXNXNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMWO,       'x0o.  .. .:dOdoONN0xod0NNXkdk0XNK0Oxdl::oKX0kxxdxdlclkXWMNKXN0KXX0O0XXNXOOO000NWKkkxdk0Ol:::ldkxl;.,lxxdoodkO0OOK0dlc,,oKWWNWWMMWNWWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNKKNMMMMMWOollllodxxxxdxkOklldO0kc.         'cc;:ccoxd'    .,.:0NWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMNx. ':.  .cKWK;    .lOkl:cxOKN0xkNMMWKO0XK0OOxlodxOKOdox00c..:o0WWNKOO0XXKKK0Okxxk00KWMNOk0NWWXOOXW0ddxxdc,,:odolodxkO00OkdllclooookXNK0NMMMWXXWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWWWWMMWNNWWNNX0OOkxxxxkKNWWXK0xdol;'.     .;dkkxl'  ..     ,xc.:KMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMWKl. .kK, .xNMMO'   'od;,cddokKXXWMWXNNX0kxOOkdc:OWKxllxkdxxldO0KK0OOO0XXNNNX0OkddkO0O0XWMNKKXWMWX0NWNOo:,;lxkkkkxOK0OOkdooodxxxddddkKWMMMMNKKWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMX00KNMWNNXKKXXOdlldKNKxdkOOkxxdoodxl.   ..;c;'.            .o0c.lNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMNk,.'l0Kl.'OWMMWk.   ..  ;dxxOOOKNMWXNWMMXOOkkxOKX0dldOkc. .'ckXWKOxxO00O0XWW0kOOO0XNX0O0KWWKOKWWNKOxol'.cdO0Oxxk0NNKkolloxxdlcldO00OkOKWMMMWNWMMNXNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWWWNK0KXWWWNKOO00xc:lxxxxkkOOO0Kx..;lldl.       'lxo.    .dk'.kWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMWXk:.,xXNk, .kWMMMM0,      ,okxdx0NWNKOKWMWXOkkkO0KKkdxOOl. .';''dXXxdxkOOOOKK00OOOKXWMMNKxx0WWNNKkxkkdddxodO0KKOkkkkdlccoxdlccldkkxkkkxxOKK00NWNOkKNXXNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNX0K0o;cdkO0XNKOkkxxxkKXKOkdd:...:k0Okd,   .c000Xk.    ... ;KMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMWO,.'dXW0c.  :XMMMMMNo.   .cxdoxKNX0O00OOKXOk0NMNXK0Oxl,..  ,:''oKKOxx0NWKOOOO0O0KKKNWWKxodOXWXOxlclONK0OkxxkOOxdxkxccldkkxddxkxxxxxxdoc:xXXOxkKWN0OKWWXKWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWXXWMMWNKxc;col:cdkOOKKXXKKK0Okl,':xxxxdxOK0o;..',.'dXd.    .,..dWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMX: .lOKd''. 'OWMMMMMMO'    ':kNNKkkOOxxkOKKKX00NMW0d;.  .':oo,.o0kxxKWWKOkO0KKXKXNXXNKkxkKNK0K0xdOXWWKxc::ldkkxkkl;:d00OOkkkdodxxxo:,;;cx0xlclx0NMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWKKWWN0koc;.   .cOXNXX0kxkO000xc:ldo:;cd0NXKXXOkxkkkOX0;        'kNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMO'  .;;  .'c0WMMMMMMMK;     ,dxxxOkddkO0KXXOxxOKOo,  .:dkkdc'..lO0KK0dldOKXXXXNNKOxxOKXNKkxkKXK0KKOo;..'oO0OO0kollkNMN0kdlloxkdc;,:oxxdo;. .d0Ox0NMMMMMMWWWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNOxxo,   .:dkOOOOO00OOOkxOkl,';cdxdooxOOOO0000OO0XO,.        .cOWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMWk.       ;ONMMMMMMMMMNo.   .:clxxddddxOKX0kxxdoo;..:x0Oo;. .,d0Kxccc;lOKKKXWWKOkdxkKXKxddOXWXKXKk;. .cxkxdodo;.oKXWN0dlldkko;',cxkxdoc;.  .;dOO0KKOO0XWWKKNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMW0xdd:.'oxxkkkO00KNNNX0xodo' .,:,;cxKXNNKKNMMWNXNW0xxxkkOOkd:'.'lKWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMWx.    .;kNMMMMMMMMMMMMO'     .,lxkc:xXKocoodxkOd;:OXk;.  'lkK0o,  .ck0kO0KX0l,cxOOkdooxKWWX00XKl..cdOOkollllolkXKkdoodk0Ol,,lxOkxddll:;;:dkxdokXXOxxkOKWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWNWMMMMMMMWKkxdc..,oOKNWMWNXK0KNNOddo,   .cxKWNKXWNWN0000kxOkodOO0KXXx;oOo''dXMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMWl .'..xNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMX:      .xxco00l..,okkdlcldOOc. .:xOxdl:..'lO0d:oxdkx:;dOx:';o0WWX0O0KOo;cxO00OxxkOO0KNXKk:,lkxc;;coxkkxkkdoc:lxkOOo,.  .;okOXWWNWWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWNNWMMMMMWK0OddkOd,.ck0KNWNNWMMMMN0kdolll,'xKOdokXMXxoOKOolood0XXNWWNXkldXW0c';xNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMWo   .xWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWx.      ..:dl,'cxxddooddl:'..,dOOOkkO000O0K0kc.. .;dO0x;.;dXWKkdxOOxc,:kNWKkkkOOOdclx0Kd:..clclkKKOxk00Okxkkkdc;'.       'oO0KNWXKNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWX0xllc,.  'dKX0OkKWMWWWX0OkOkd:,cxdodx0NOc:OXxldd:l0NXXXWW0od0NMMMWO;.;kKNWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMWx. 'kWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMK;       ...:dkdccxOOdc.  .:x00O0XNWWNXKK0Odc'  .l0Kd;'ckXNOocokkl;;oO00xc,:xxo:...lOOxdxdld0NNKOxdxO0OOK0oc' ..'c,  .';cc:dkOKNWWWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWKddko'  .oKXNK00XXXXXNNNX0Okddkxoxd;,:ccxOKNXXd,lK0OOl;dOkk0KK0dloo:..,:loxOXNWMMWNX0kkKNMMM
MMWk',0MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWx.       ,oo:.,oxddxkdc:dOOO0KK00XWMW0xl,. ..  ;dl,,ckXKxlcdkd:';dOk:,c,   ...;loodxxxxk0K00OkxdxxkO00kc..';lxkkdccodoclOXNNXNX0XWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWKc,;.   .cO0Oxxk0KXNX0KXWMNx,,cdx:  .'lOo,:dO0::KN0k;.:dol:;'.. .cx00kkd:';:,;clc:,..,,'dWMM
MMMO;oWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMK;      .'',;.'cdxxl,':okO0XK0O0NX0Odclllloxl..';,;dOklcoxxl;:cokko,..'.  .;oxxkkxxxkdoxOK0kxdxddxk0kl..:kOkxkkxl,,,..;dOKK0OKNNWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWXKKKkl'  .'cxkkkkOKX0OO0K000d;:dd'   .ox;  ...'..,cc.  ..       .oOOkOkxd:.cko:,.    :KO,lWMM
MMMKdOMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWx.       ,occxOd,.   ;kK0OO0KWNkcokKNWN0xxxxxOKNXkl;. ':,..:lloxl.    .cddl;.'cdxdoooodxkkkdolllodxxdoxKX0kkdoc.     .,:lloxXWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNK0Oxx0KOd:..;:lxkkkO00kxk0XX0O0XXk:.    ''.                        'lxOkdl:;:cdOKNXx,  'Ok,;0MMM
MMMWXNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMX:         'lc'     ,kxlokOKKOxkKWMWKkxxO00XNNKOl.            ..     .:c;.  .:lloolcldddoooodxO000kxkkOKXOc.         .;ldO00KOkxxxkO0XNWMMMWWNWMMWNXKK0kdlccllodc. .lXWX0OkOKNNXKOkO0XO:.     .'                         .cl:,..;dkOO0KKKKKc .dx.'kWMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWk'                 ..  'oO0OOKWWX0OO00OkOOxc,.                             ';;:codooodddkKXKkoc;;,,o0Od:.           .:xO0kk00kO0O0KXWWMWNWWKOO0KNNXOO0KOkkxo;. ..'cdO00O00OO00O0XNWWX:       .'           .ll,.      ...      .clcokKk;...  lO;.dWMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNx'                     cOKKK0Oxk00kddxko,.                                   . .;lxxxkOxl;.       ';.       .':;..,lxO00xoxkxO00O0KNMMWNWMMWNNWMMMNKKXNN0:.     ';,',lolcoOK00XWN0xc:c,      . ,o;       .:x00kdoollxKKxc'.     ...'.     ;Kd.cXMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWKl.                  .ododo,;odlcokkl.                                  ..      .;'.         .     .:c,.'ldddoodk0OO0OOkkkkxxxxkO0OO00XWX0KNMMMMMMWWWMMWO:.         .;lodo:'colllodl;..:c,.   .:'          .;:lodxxkkOO0K0xc,.          'OK;'OWMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNo.                  .     .':xkl,.                  .';clo:,','..';ldkk:.,ll'.. ..  .'':lddo:,:oxdl,'lOOxookNNKkllxkkkk0KXNX0k0NN0OXNWKk0NMMMMMMMMMMMMNd.             .;.  .cdo;. .lxd'.'  .;.    .;;.               .':dOKKkdl:'     ;d,.oNMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMXl.                        .ll.                  'cxKNWWWKKNNX0O00kkxoccdOd;.,,.,c,:x00OOOOOkkxxo'  ;dkkkkOkdoc:cdXWMWWNKko:,..dKNXXWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWk.                   .      ..       .     .xOl.                   .;coxxl.      .oXMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNk,                                          'oOK00NMMMN0OKKkdxo;.  .lodddool;;oO0kdc'.,lc;'.;o:. .:olc;;::coddolc:;;,'.   ;o,cKWMWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMXl                                           .                           .......,o0WMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWKc.         .c'.:xkdc.                    .cxxxkOOxdl;....           .;:,,cddl;.                 .                       .d00XWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNOl.                                                   .':looodxdoooodddxxkO000KKXWMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNx'        .';',ok0Od:'.                     ',.                         ..                                             .c000NMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWKo.                                .lkkkxxxdddooolooodkOKNWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWXo.   .'cdkOkkkkxc..';.     ..'.                                                                                        'kNXXMMMMMMMMMMMNK0xko.  ...                      ..;lxOKNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMO'   ,l:,:ldxxdl'      .;lx0XN0c.                     .';:::;,'..                                ....           ..,,.   .;cdKMMMMMMMMXOxx;... .cKXOkkkkkxxddoolloooddxxkOKXWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWo        .;ll;.    .,lkKWMMMMMMWKx,              '.  'kNWMMMMWNX0Oxoc;'..                ..,:ldkO0KXO;        'oOXWWk.     'oKWWMMMMMWKo,    .xNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWO' .,cl;.,:'     .;xKWMMMMMMMMMMMMWO'           .o0l. ,0MMMMMMMMMMMMMMWNX0OkxdollllloddxO0KXWMMMMMMMMMO.      .o00XWMWx.   .d00000KWMMMMXc.  .dWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNx..cOK0OkkOx,   .;kNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMXc          .d0kd; ;XMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMK;   .;ok0XWMMMMWo    .;xXWKKWMMMMMX:  .kMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMXl. ;XNOdddol;. .lx0WMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNl.        'dxd00;.dNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMXc   :0K0OKNMMMMWk;.   .dNWNWMMMMMMWx. 'OMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMKc   'l;..,c'   ,ONXNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMXc         .,:OKOc:0MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNl.  .cdk0XWMMMXkx0O:   lNMMMMMMMMMNd. cXMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWO;      .,;cl'  cKMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWO'          ,kX0xcxNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWd.  :KMMMMMMMKodXMMNd. .c0NWMMMMWOo;..dWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWO,       .dk,  .lXMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWk.         .kWW0::KMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNo. .lKWMMMMWOlxNMMMMW0; .o0XNMMMWK:  .OMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWKc.       ..   :XMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMK:         ;KMK:.oNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMX:.;xKWMMMMNxckWMMMMMMMK: .dNWMMMW0; .oNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNd.    .lo.   ;KMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWx.        ;KNx'.dWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWx:dXWMMMMMNo,xWMMMMMMMMMXc 'kWMMMWO' '0MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMK:     ';'.   oWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMK:       .oNO;..xWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWk:oKNWMMMMNl.lNMMMMMMMMMMMXc .:0MMMNo..xWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWx.      ..   ;KMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWO'      ,OO:  ,0WMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMK;'xNMMMMMWd.:KMMMMMMMMMMMMMK,  lNMMMK; 'OWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMXc ..  .lkkc..xWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNd.     ...  .oNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMk..d0NMMWKo';0WMMMMMMMMMMMMMWd. .oXMMWk' ,0MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMK:.   .oXMX: :XMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMXl        ...lXMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMK;.;xxxkd,.,OWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMXc  ;0MMMW0;.oNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM0;     :KNo..xWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM0;      .c00ooXMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWx. . .;;..xWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMK; .cKWMMWO'.xNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWx.     .xO; 'OWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMW0:       ;d:.oNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMK:       '0MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWO'  'lkXNO' ,0MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM0,      .'.  ,OWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMK;          .oKWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWx.      .dNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMX;     .,.  .dWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMXc            .dNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWx.           .l0WMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNk;      .oXMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM0'      ,ol, .cKMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWd.             :KMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMXc.         .'''lKWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMK;  'll..,xXMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWx.      ;0WXo. :KMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWXx'        ':o:.:KMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNOxdl'     'x0x:;kNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWO, ,0Wk'  'oKWMMMMMMMMMMMMKcckOo.  .lKNk,.c0KNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWNNOc'.    .lOXNx';0MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMK:   .:xddxc'xWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWk'.:xo.    'xWMMMMMMMMMMMMWWMMWk'   .cdl. .;0MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWNKx,    ..,,. ;0MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMXklcclol:loo0WMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMW0xdolc::;;:xNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMW0lc:;;;,'..lXMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMXkxxxxxxxxxkXMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWWWWWWWWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWWWWWWWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWWWWWWNXXNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
\end{filecontents*}
\newsavebox{\asciiart}
\newcommand{\pig}{\raisebox{.8\height}{\resizebox{1.5ex}{!}{\usebox{\asciiart}}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{lrbox}{\asciiart}
\begin{varwidth}{\maxdimen}
\noindent\lstinputlisting[basicstyle=\ttfamily]{pig.txt}
\end{varwidth}
\end{lrbox}%

 \scalebox{50}{\pig{}}

\end{document}
```

to get:

[image]

Comment: How did you do it?

Comment: @pushpen.paul you take a image that you like, convert it online into ascii. And, then you plot it in TeX.

Answer (score 7):

There is, now, also my pig :-) drawn with Matcha editor https://www.mathcha.io

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} 

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
\draw [fill=pink,fill opacity=1 ]  (128.4,142.2) .. controls (128.4,117.35) and (157.84,97.2) .. (194.15,97.2) .. controls (230.46,97.2) and (259.9,117.35) .. (259.9,142.2) .. controls (259.9,167.05) and (230.46,187.2) .. (194.15,187.2) .. controls (157.84,187.2) and (128.4,167.05) .. (128.4,142.2) -- cycle ;
\draw  [fill=pink,fill opacity=1] (100.87,153.64) .. controls (99.86,138.46) and (116.02,125.02) .. (136.97,123.63) .. controls (157.91,122.23) and (175.71,133.42) .. (176.72,148.61) .. controls (177.72,163.79) and (161.56,177.23) .. (140.62,178.62) .. controls (119.67,180.02) and (101.88,168.83) .. (100.87,153.64) -- cycle ; 
\draw   (145.63,151.23) .. controls (154.17,152.67) and (157.02,156.91) .. (151.99,160.69) .. controls (146.97,164.47) and (135.98,166.37) .. (127.45,164.93) .. controls (118.92,163.49) and (116.07,159.25) .. (121.09,155.47) .. controls (126.11,151.69) and (137.1,149.79) .. (145.63,151.23) -- cycle ;
\draw   (143.25,141.06) .. controls (142.84,139.99) and (143.37,139.13) .. (144.44,139.13) .. controls (145.51,139.13) and (146.71,139.99) .. (147.13,141.06) .. controls (147.54,142.13) and (147,143) .. (145.93,143) .. controls (144.86,143) and (143.66,142.13) .. (143.25,141.06) -- cycle ;
\draw   (121.49,141.48) .. controls (122.61,141.24) and (123.38,141.9) .. (123.22,142.96) .. controls (123.05,144.02) and (122.01,145.07) .. (120.89,145.31) .. controls (119.77,145.55) and (118.99,144.89) .. (119.16,143.83) .. controls (119.32,142.78) and (120.37,141.72) .. (121.49,141.48) -- cycle ; 
\draw   (143.79,154.13) -- (143.79,161.08) ;
\draw    (126.2,155.43) -- (127.45,162.93) ;
\draw[fill=pink]   (103.37,133.64) -- (106.1,126.87) -- (116.37,122.5) -- (123.14,125.23) -- (125.16,129.99) -- (125.16,129.99) -- (105.39,138.39) -- (105.39,138.39) -- cycle ;
\draw[fill=pink]   (136.97,123.63) -- (142.57,118.03) -- (152.85,118.03) -- (158.45,123.63) -- (158.45,129.23) -- (158.45,129.23) -- (136.97,129.23) -- (136.97,129.23) -- cycle ;
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75] [line join = round][line cap = round] (259.69,142.57) .. controls (265.17,140.64) and (270.84,140.56) .. (268.91,146.69) .. controls (268.43,148.18) and (265.32,149.85) .. (263.04,149.05) .. controls (255.71,146.47) and (266.59,138.8) .. (269.74,137.85) .. controls (270.26,137.69) and (271.05,137.55) .. (271.42,137.85) .. controls (275.04,140.76) and (276.45,142.97) .. (276.45,146.69) .. controls (276.45,148.01) and (272.97,144.29) .. (273.93,143.16) .. controls (275.56,141.25) and (277.54,138.87) .. (280.63,138.44) .. controls (286.59,137.6) and (289.48,142.47) .. (284.82,144.92) .. controls (283.6,145.57) and (282.83,141.83) .. (283.15,141.39) .. controls (284.7,139.2) and (285.57,139.62) .. (288.18,139.62) ;
5) .. controls (252.49,162.5) and (255.86,163.51) .. (255.86,164.76) -- cycle ;
\draw[fill=yellow]   (57.5,85.67) .. controls (48.76,81.11) and (44.91,71.22) .. (48.89,63.57) .. controls (52.88,55.92) and (63.2,53.41) .. (71.94,57.97) .. controls (65.77,58.27) and (59.89,61.78) .. (56.81,67.69) .. controls (53.72,73.61) and (54.21,80.44) .. (57.5,85.67) -- cycle ;
\draw   (85.61,59.25) .. controls (85.41,58.24) and (86.07,57.24) .. (87.31,56.68) .. controls (88.55,56.11) and (90.16,56.08) .. (91.45,56.59) .. controls (91.91,56.01) and (92.74,55.6) .. (93.7,55.5) .. controls (94.66,55.4) and (95.64,55.61) .. (96.33,56.08) .. controls (96.72,55.55) and (97.48,55.19) .. (98.35,55.13) .. controls (99.22,55.08) and (100.07,55.33) .. (100.6,55.8) .. controls (101.3,55.24) and (102.42,55) .. (103.47,55.19) .. controls (104.52,55.39) and (105.31,55.97) .. (105.5,56.7) .. controls (106.36,56.86) and (107.08,57.27) .. (107.47,57.82) .. controls (107.85,58.37) and (107.87,59.01) .. (107.52,59.57) .. controls (108.37,60.32) and (108.57,61.33) .. (108.04,62.21) .. controls (107.52,63.09) and (106.35,63.71) .. (104.97,63.85) .. controls (104.96,64.68) and (104.3,65.43) .. (103.24,65.83) .. controls (102.18,66.23) and (100.88,66.2) .. (99.86,65.77) .. controls (99.42,66.76) and (98.19,67.49) .. (96.7,67.64) .. controls (95.2,67.79) and (93.72,67.34) .. (92.88,66.48) .. controls (91.85,66.9) and (90.62,67.02) .. (89.46,66.82) .. controls (88.3,66.61) and (87.31,66.09) .. (86.71,65.38) .. controls (85.66,65.46) and (84.64,65.09) .. (84.17,64.45) .. controls (83.69,63.8) and (83.85,63.02) .. (84.58,62.5) .. controls (83.64,62.12) and (83.16,61.37) .. (83.39,60.64) .. controls (83.62,59.91) and (84.51,59.37) .. (85.59,59.29) ; \draw   (84.58,62.5) .. controls (85.02,62.68) and (85.53,62.76) .. (86.04,62.73)(86.71,65.38) .. controls (86.93,65.36) and (87.14,65.32) .. (87.35,65.27)(92.88,66.48) .. controls (92.72,66.32) and (92.59,66.15) .. (92.49,65.97)(99.86,65.77) .. controls (99.94,65.59) and (99.99,65.4) .. (100.01,65.21)(104.97,63.85) .. controls (104.98,62.97) and (104.25,62.16) .. (103.09,61.78)(107.52,59.57) .. controls (107.34,59.87) and (107.05,60.14) .. (106.69,60.35)(105.5,56.7) .. controls (105.53,56.82) and (105.55,56.95) .. (105.54,57.07)(100.6,55.8) .. controls (100.42,55.95) and (100.28,56.1) .. (100.17,56.27)(96.33,56.08) .. controls (96.24,56.21) and (96.17,56.34) .. (96.13,56.48)(91.45,56.59) .. controls (91.72,56.7) and (91.97,56.83) .. (92.2,56.98)(85.61,59.25) .. controls (85.64,59.39) and (85.68,59.53) .. (85.74,59.67) ;
\draw   (125.61,55.25) .. controls (125.41,54.24) and (126.07,53.24) .. (127.31,52.68) .. controls (128.55,52.11) and (130.16,52.08) .. (131.45,52.59) .. controls (131.91,52.01) and (132.74,51.6) .. (133.7,51.5) .. controls (134.66,51.4) and (135.64,51.61) .. (136.33,52.08) .. controls (136.72,51.55) and (137.48,51.19) .. (138.35,51.13) .. controls (139.22,51.08) and (140.07,51.33) .. (140.6,51.8) .. controls (141.3,51.24) and (142.42,51) .. (143.47,51.19) .. controls (144.52,51.39) and (145.31,51.97) .. (145.5,52.7) .. controls (146.36,52.86) and (147.08,53.27) .. (147.47,53.82) .. controls (147.85,54.37) and (147.87,55.01) .. (147.52,55.57) .. controls (148.37,56.32) and (148.57,57.33) .. (148.04,58.21) .. controls (147.52,59.09) and (146.35,59.71) .. (144.97,59.85) .. controls (144.96,60.68) and (144.3,61.43) .. (143.24,61.83) .. controls (142.18,62.23) and (140.88,62.2) .. (139.86,61.77) .. controls (139.42,62.76) and (138.19,63.49) .. (136.7,63.64) .. controls (135.2,63.79) and (133.72,63.34) .. (132.88,62.48) .. controls (131.85,62.9) and (130.62,63.02) .. (129.46,62.82) .. controls (128.3,62.61) and (127.31,62.09) .. (126.71,61.38) .. controls (125.66,61.46) and (124.64,61.09) .. (124.17,60.45) .. controls (123.69,59.8) and (123.85,59.02) .. (124.58,58.5) .. controls (123.64,58.12) and (123.16,57.37) .. (123.39,56.64) .. controls (123.62,55.91) and (124.51,55.37) .. (125.59,55.29) ; \draw   (124.58,58.5) .. controls (125.02,58.68) and (125.53,58.76) .. (126.04,58.73)(126.71,61.38) .. controls (126.93,61.36) and (127.14,61.32) .. (127.35,61.27)(132.88,62.48) .. controls (132.72,62.32) and (132.59,62.15) .. (132.49,61.97)(139.86,61.77) .. controls (139.94,61.59) and (139.99,61.4) .. (140.01,61.21)(144.97,59.85) .. controls (144.98,58.97) and (144.25,58.16) .. (143.09,57.78)(147.52,55.57) .. controls (147.34,55.87) and (147.05,56.14) .. (146.69,56.35)(145.5,52.7) .. controls (145.53,52.82) and (145.55,52.95) .. (145.54,53.07)(140.6,51.8) .. controls (140.42,51.95) and (140.28,52.1) .. (140.17,52.27)(136.33,52.08) .. controls (136.24,52.21) and (136.17,52.34) .. (136.13,52.48)(131.45,52.59) .. controls (131.72,52.7) and (131.97,52.83) .. (132.2,52.98)(125.61,55.25) .. controls (125.64,55.39) and (125.68,55.53) .. (125.74,55.67) ;
\draw   (16.28,55.47) .. controls (16.07,54.24) and (16.73,53.03) .. (17.98,52.34) .. controls (19.22,51.65) and (20.83,51.61) .. (22.12,52.24) .. controls (22.57,51.53) and (23.41,51.03) .. (24.37,50.91) .. controls (25.33,50.79) and (26.31,51.05) .. (27,51.62) .. controls (27.39,50.97) and (28.15,50.54) .. (29.02,50.47) .. controls (29.89,50.4) and (30.73,50.71) .. (31.26,51.28) .. controls (31.97,50.6) and (33.08,50.31) .. (34.13,50.54) .. controls (35.18,50.77) and (35.97,51.49) .. (36.17,52.37) .. controls (37.03,52.57) and (37.74,53.06) .. (38.13,53.73) .. controls (38.52,54.39) and (38.54,55.17) .. (38.19,55.85) .. controls (39.04,56.76) and (39.24,57.98) .. (38.71,59.05) .. controls (38.19,60.12) and (37.02,60.87) .. (35.64,61.04) .. controls (35.63,62.04) and (34.97,62.96) .. (33.9,63.44) .. controls (32.84,63.92) and (31.55,63.89) .. (30.52,63.36) .. controls (30.09,64.56) and (28.86,65.45) .. (27.36,65.63) .. controls (25.87,65.82) and (24.38,65.27) .. (23.55,64.23) .. controls (22.52,64.74) and (21.28,64.89) .. (20.12,64.64) .. controls (18.96,64.39) and (17.97,63.76) .. (17.38,62.89) .. controls (16.33,62.99) and (15.31,62.54) .. (14.83,61.76) .. controls (14.36,60.98) and (14.52,60.04) .. (15.24,59.4) .. controls (14.31,58.94) and (13.83,58.03) .. (14.06,57.15) .. controls (14.29,56.27) and (15.17,55.61) .. (16.25,55.51) ; \draw   (15.24,59.4) .. controls (15.69,59.62) and (16.2,59.71) .. (16.71,59.68)(17.38,62.89) .. controls (17.6,62.87) and (17.81,62.82) .. (18.02,62.76)(23.55,64.23) .. controls (23.39,64.03) and (23.26,63.83) .. (23.16,63.61)(30.52,63.36) .. controls (30.6,63.14) and (30.66,62.92) .. (30.68,62.69)(35.64,61.04) .. controls (35.65,59.97) and (34.92,58.99) .. (33.76,58.53)(38.19,55.85) .. controls (38,56.21) and (37.72,56.53) .. (37.35,56.79)(36.17,52.37) .. controls (36.2,52.52) and (36.21,52.67) .. (36.21,52.82)(31.26,51.28) .. controls (31.09,51.45) and (30.94,51.64) .. (30.83,51.85)(27,51.62) .. controls (26.91,51.77) and (26.84,51.94) .. (26.79,52.11)(22.12,52.24) .. controls (22.39,52.37) and (22.64,52.53) .. (22.87,52.71)(16.28,55.47) .. controls (16.3,55.63) and (16.35,55.8) .. (16.41,55.96) ;
\draw[fill=brown]   (272.27,179.58) -- (272.4,215.16) -- (115.9,215.73) -- (115.77,180.16) -- cycle ;
\draw   (156.48,168.75) .. controls (153.52,171.47) and (149.99,173.52) .. (145.99,174.68) .. controls (140.52,176.26) and (134.9,175.97) .. (129.65,174.15) -- cycle ;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

(This answer is [suggested by KJO](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/479769/draw-saving-money-pig/479774?noredirect=1#comment1212311_479774))

Let's hope to have a year filled with money!

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.80pt, x=0.80pt, yscale=-1.000000, xscale=1.000000, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
\fill[yellow,yshift=7.2cm] (15,30) rectangle (40,15);
\path[fill=black,line width=0.056pt] (11.7614,296.5612) .. controls
  (11.3851,295.9868) and (11.4156,295.6960) .. (12.1522,292.8392) .. controls
  (12.5917,291.1347) and (12.9512,289.5263) .. (12.9512,289.2649) .. controls
  (12.9512,289.0035) and (12.4849,288.4664) .. (11.9150,288.0715) .. controls
  (10.8120,287.3071) and (8.0433,284.4949) .. (7.3902,283.4755) .. controls
  (7.1101,283.0385) and (6.6579,282.8200) .. (5.8075,282.7111) .. controls
  (2.4694,282.2834) and (0.6994,279.9432) .. (-0.0230,275.0021) .. controls
  (-0.3005,273.1045) and (-0.2866,272.7630) .. (0.0919,272.1854) .. controls
  (0.3287,271.8239) and (0.7889,271.4769) .. (1.1145,271.4143) .. controls
  (3.8064,270.8964) and (4.9406,270.6343) .. (5.2960,270.4477) .. controls
  (5.5240,270.3280) and (6.1422,269.3594) .. (6.6698,268.2952) .. controls
  (7.6356,266.3469) and (9.2936,264.3698) .. (11.2099,262.8815) --
  (12.2466,262.0763) -- (11.5545,261.1688) .. controls (10.7799,260.1533) and
  (9.3930,257.2403) .. (9.1277,256.0717) -- (8.9543,255.3080) --
  (11.5481,255.4387) .. controls (14.4665,255.5857) and (18.0645,256.6356) ..
  (20.6242,258.0870) .. controls (21.4245,258.5408) and (22.3934,258.8904) ..
  (22.7772,258.8640) .. controls (23.3875,258.8219) and (23.4979,258.9405) ..
  (23.6580,259.8100) .. controls (24.1689,262.5854) and (26.2258,265.1720) ..
  (28.8628,266.3555) .. controls (30.7667,267.2099) and (33.5066,267.3323) ..
  (35.4030,266.6477) .. controls (37.0986,266.0356) and (38.9808,264.5459) ..
  (39.9326,263.0626) -- (40.7698,261.7580) -- (42.1396,262.6008) .. controls
  (44.0447,263.7731) and (47.0598,266.7080) .. (48.0085,268.3137) .. controls
  (48.4853,269.1206) and (48.9906,269.6592) .. (49.2738,269.6624) .. controls
  (49.9018,269.6694) and (51.5831,268.9567) .. (51.5702,268.6889) .. controls
  (51.5642,268.5724) and (51.1821,268.2389) .. (50.7202,267.9478) .. controls
  (49.4649,267.1569) and (48.6700,265.8172) .. (48.6700,264.4926) .. controls
  (48.6700,263.5579) and (48.8094,263.2473) .. (49.4840,262.6797) .. controls
  (49.9318,262.3030) and (50.5925,261.9947) .. (50.9524,261.9947) .. controls
  (52.5243,261.9947) and (54.2980,263.6473) .. (54.8197,265.5981) .. controls
  (54.9902,266.2356) and (55.2833,266.7572) .. (55.4710,266.7572) .. controls
  (55.6587,266.7572) and (56.2840,266.3310) .. (56.8607,265.8100) .. controls
  (57.9885,264.7911) and (58.8201,264.7508) .. (59.1215,265.7003) .. controls
  (59.4670,266.7891) and (57.3965,268.5769) .. (55.2846,269.0134) .. controls
  (54.7753,269.1186) and (53.9204,269.5987) .. (53.3849,270.0802) .. controls
  (52.8495,270.5616) and (51.8046,271.1711) .. (51.0630,271.4345) .. controls
  (49.7563,271.8986) and (49.7210,271.9379) .. (49.9199,272.7087) .. controls
  (50.0328,273.1462) and (50.1222,274.5756) .. (50.1185,275.8853) .. controls
  (50.1078,279.6723) and (48.7426,282.8163) .. (45.7530,285.9395) .. controls
  (45.0608,286.6627) and (44.6869,287.3330) .. (44.5724,288.0562) .. controls
  (44.0349,291.4502) and (42.7403,296.0276) .. (42.1217,296.7213) .. controls
  (41.7648,297.1215) and (41.1947,297.1843) .. (37.9195,297.1843) .. controls
  (34.2202,297.1843) and (34.1203,297.1693) .. (33.7174,296.5545) .. controls
  (33.3396,295.9779) and (33.3494,295.7635) .. (33.8333,294.0175) --
  (34.3617,292.1104) -- (32.9831,292.3322) .. controls (31.3480,292.5953) and
  (24.0735,292.6290) .. (22.7206,292.3798) -- (21.7743,292.2054) --
  (21.1790,294.2318) .. controls (20.2900,297.2577) and (20.4197,297.1843) ..
  (15.9591,297.1843) .. controls (12.2713,297.1843) and (12.1588,297.1676) ..
  (11.7614,296.5612) -- cycle(36.7032,282.1261) .. controls (37.1792,281.9373)
  and (37.6852,281.5650) .. (37.8277,281.2989) .. controls (37.9701,281.0327)
  and (38.0867,279.2800) .. (38.0867,277.4041) .. controls (38.0867,274.0791)
  and (38.0695,273.9771) .. (37.4036,273.3518) -- (36.7206,272.7103) --
  (26.8422,272.7103) .. controls (21.4091,272.7103) and (16.8699,272.8043) ..
  (16.7551,272.9192) .. controls (16.4775,273.1969) and (16.2807,279.3879) ..
  (16.5024,280.8666) -- (16.6772,282.0322) -- (18.3200,282.3054) .. controls
  (20.7458,282.7089) and (35.5994,282.5640) .. (36.7032,282.1262) --
  cycle(15.5779,269.7642) .. controls (16.2980,268.8487) and (16.2702,268.2000)
  .. (15.4768,267.4066) .. controls (14.2164,266.1462) and (12.4221,266.9216) ..
  (12.4221,268.7266) .. controls (12.4221,270.4142) and (14.5232,271.1050) ..
  (15.5779,269.7642) -- cycle(52.9033,266.3564) .. controls (52.9033,265.8422)
  and (51.1535,263.9210) .. (50.9083,264.1661) .. controls (50.5218,264.5526)
  and (51.0994,265.7360) .. (51.9182,266.2353) .. controls (52.9422,266.8596)
  and (52.9033,266.8548) .. (52.9033,266.3564) -- cycle(30.1883,265.2075) ..
  controls (28.4468,264.5878) and (27.6205,263.9904) .. (26.5183,262.5543) ..
  controls (25.4449,261.1557) and (25.0385,259.6658) .. (25.1760,257.6333) ..
  controls (25.3040,255.7406) and (25.9513,254.2863) .. (27.2387,252.9989) ..
  controls (28.7839,251.4537) and (29.9551,251.0145) .. (32.5304,251.0145) ..
  controls (34.4908,251.0145) and (34.9321,251.1048) .. (35.9700,251.7185) ..
  controls (38.5102,253.2205) and (39.7803,255.4241) .. (39.7581,258.2905) ..
  controls (39.7418,260.3841) and (39.2619,261.5926) .. (37.8302,263.1459) ..
  controls (35.7943,265.3546) and (32.8406,266.1515) .. (30.1883,265.2075) --
  cycle(33.1852,263.1830) .. controls (33.3344,262.8932) and (33.7790,262.3390)
  .. (34.1733,261.9513) .. controls (35.7409,260.4100) and (35.3328,258.8215) ..
  (33.0882,257.7276) .. controls (31.3987,256.9043) and (31.0221,256.3971) ..
  (31.6408,255.7784) .. controls (32.1808,255.2384) and (33.3015,255.4480) ..
  (33.8194,256.1859) .. controls (34.2616,256.8158) and (35.0590,256.8610) ..
  (35.2862,256.2689) .. controls (35.4987,255.7152) and (34.8047,254.6469) ..
  (33.9920,254.2766) .. controls (33.6471,254.1194) and (33.2920,253.7004) ..
  (33.2029,253.3454) .. controls (32.9895,252.4954) and (31.9091,252.5842) ..
  (31.7844,253.4619) .. controls (31.7379,253.7893) and (31.5837,254.0572) ..
  (31.4416,254.0572) .. controls (31.2996,254.0572) and (30.8912,254.3495) ..
  (30.5340,254.7067) .. controls (30.0660,255.1747) and (29.8846,255.6450) ..
  (29.8846,256.3904) .. controls (29.8846,257.6560) and (30.7129,258.5878) ..
  (32.2464,259.0472) .. controls (33.4580,259.4102) and (33.6899,259.6716) ..
  (33.4557,260.4096) .. controls (33.2215,261.1474) and (31.6073,261.1457) ..
  (31.1461,260.4076) .. controls (30.6598,259.6289) and (29.6200,259.7030) ..
  (29.6200,260.5164) .. controls (29.6200,261.1223) and (30.9273,262.5243) ..
  (31.4924,262.5243) .. controls (31.6267,262.5243) and (31.7367,262.7425) ..
  (31.7367,263.0093) .. controls (31.7367,263.9995) and (32.7051,264.1159) ..
  (33.1852,263.1834) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Edit 1

Shorter version WITH CHINESE!

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[black] (0,0) ellipse (3cm and 2.5cm);
\fill[black,rounded corners] (-1.5,-2)--(-2,-3.5)--(-1,-3.5)--(-.5,-2);
\fill[black,rounded corners] (1,-2)--(0.5,-3.5)--(1.5,-3.5)--(2.5,-1);
\fill[black,rounded corners=1mm] (-2.5,0.5)--(-4,0)--(-3.75,-1)--(-2,-1.5);
\fill[black] (0,2)--(-3,2.25)--(-2,1);
\draw[line width=3mm] (1,0)--(3.5,1.5);
\node[line width=2mm,draw=white,fill=black,circle,font=\sffamily\color{white}\Huge,scale=1.5] at (80:3cm and 2.5cm) {\$};
\fill[white] (-2,1) circle (2mm);
\node[fill=red,font=\color{yellow}\huge] at (0,-.25) {%
\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}
新年快乐!
\end{CJK*}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok I know I'm picky (piggy:-) but you could squeeze 新年快乐 in the box ?

Comment: @KJO Well I am not familiar with typing Chinese in LaTeX, so would you please add it for me? It will be very appreciated. I know I can't use `babel` and that is why I am feeling lazy ;-) Happy (not new anymore) year!

Comment: Good point year of the pig 豬年 (synonymous with a year of prosperity) but a good single character may simply be fu 福

Comment: @KJO Just learned `CJKutf8` ;-) See the edited answer!

Comment: WoW ! take +2 for the colours

Answer (score 6):

With the `pgfornament` package:

```
\documentclass[margin=10mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfornament}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfornament[color=red!50!white]{111}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]