# Draw saving money pig (Piggy Bank)

Tags: tikz-pgf

I use LaTeX, Texmaker and `\documentclass{article}`

Related question: [Welcoming 2019 Lunar New Year: How to draw a (lovely) pig?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/473287/welcoming-2019-lunar-new-year-how-to-draw-a-lovely-pig)

I want to draw saving money pig with Ti*k*Z.

Please see image

[image]

Thanks so much

Comment: Do you really mean "Draw something with `tcolorbox`"? Btw, please add an MWE - TeX.SE is not and never a just-do-it-for-me service.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is just a `do-it-for-me`question. -1 --> no MWE.

Comment: Please don't downvote below a score of -1, even if the question in its current form needs some improvement. A score of -1 is enough to show that the question needs work, anything below that is of no use. Also, if you downvote or vote to close, please leave a comment explaining why you did so, but wait at least 24 hours after asking the OP for improvements to the question before voting to close.

Comment: @Raaja Before closing give the OP time to improve his/her answer

Comment: @CarLaTeX yes I do understand. However, OP is a long-time user. Hence, I voted to close. Nevertheless, I do wait for new users. But, from now on I shall wait before I vote to close.

Comment: @Raaja Thanks! :)

Comment: @CarLaTeX you are welcome ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> This site dislikes just-do-it-for-me question, therefore make sure adding an MWE in your next question! (anyway you are not a new user anymore.)

I answer a JDIFM question because I actually don't put any efforts to it. I just went to Prof. Inkscape's house to ask him, and very quickly he gave me his code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.80pt, x=0.80pt, yscale=-1.000000, xscale=1.000000, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
\fill[yellow,yshift=7.2cm] (15,30) rectangle (40,15);
\path[fill=black,line width=0.056pt] (11.7614,296.5612) .. controls
  (11.3851,295.9868) and (11.4156,295.6960) .. (12.1522,292.8392) .. controls
  (12.5917,291.1347) and (12.9512,289.5263) .. (12.9512,289.2649) .. controls
  (12.9512,289.0035) and (12.4849,288.4664) .. (11.9150,288.0715) .. controls
  (10.8120,287.3071) and (8.0433,284.4949) .. (7.3902,283.4755) .. controls
  (7.1101,283.0385) and (6.6579,282.8200) .. (5.8075,282.7111) .. controls
  (2.4694,282.2834) and (0.6994,279.9432) .. (-0.0230,275.0021) .. controls
  (-0.3005,273.1045) and (-0.2866,272.7630) .. (0.0919,272.1854) .. controls
  (0.3287,271.8239) and (0.7889,271.4769) .. (1.1145,271.4143) .. controls
  (3.8064,270.8964) and (4.9406,270.6343) .. (5.2960,270.4477) .. controls
  (5.5240,270.3280) and (6.1422,269.3594) .. (6.6698,268.2952) .. controls
  (7.6356,266.3469) and (9.2936,264.3698) .. (11.2099,262.8815) --
  (12.2466,262.0763) -- (11.5545,261.1688) .. controls (10.7799,260.1533) and
  (9.3930,257.2403) .. (9.1277,256.0717) -- (8.9543,255.3080) --
  (11.5481,255.4387) .. controls (14.4665,255.5857) and (18.0645,256.6356) ..
  (20.6242,258.0870) .. controls (21.4245,258.5408) and (22.3934,258.8904) ..
  (22.7772,258.8640) .. controls (23.3875,258.8219) and (23.4979,258.9405) ..
  (23.6580,259.8100) .. controls (24.1689,262.5854) and (26.2258,265.1720) ..
  (28.8628,266.3555) .. controls (30.7667,267.2099) and (33.5066,267.3323) ..
  (35.4030,266.6477) .. controls (37.0986,266.0356) and (38.9808,264.5459) ..
  (39.9326,263.0626) -- (40.7698,261.7580) -- (42.1396,262.6008) .. controls
  (44.0447,263.7731) and (47.0598,266.7080) .. (48.0085,268.3137) .. controls
  (48.4853,269.1206) and (48.9906,269.6592) .. (49.2738,269.6624) .. controls
  (49.9018,269.6694) and (51.5831,268.9567) .. (51.5702,268.6889) .. controls
  (51.5642,268.5724) and (51.1821,268.2389) .. (50.7202,267.9478) .. controls
  (49.4649,267.1569) and (48.6700,265.8172) .. (48.6700,264.4926) .. controls
  (48.6700,263.5579) and (48.8094,263.2473) .. (49.4840,262.6797) .. controls
  (49.9318,262.3030) and (50.5925,261.9947) .. (50.9524,261.9947) .. controls
  (52.5243,261.9947) and (54.2980,263.6473) .. (54.8197,265.5981) .. controls
  (54.9902,266.2356) and (55.2833,266.7572) .. (55.4710,266.7572) .. controls
  (55.6587,266.7572) and (56.2840,266.3310) .. (56.8607,265.8100) .. controls
  (57.9885,264.7911) and (58.8201,264.7508) .. (59.1215,265.7003) .. controls
  (59.4670,266.7891) and (57.3965,268.5769) .. (55.2846,269.0134) .. controls
  (54.7753,269.1186) and (53.9204,269.5987) .. (53.3849,270.0802) .. controls
  (52.8495,270.5616) and (51.8046,271.1711) .. (51.0630,271.4345) .. controls
  (49.7563,271.8986) and (49.7210,271.9379) .. (49.9199,272.7087) .. controls
  (50.0328,273.1462) and (50.1222,274.5756) .. (50.1185,275.8853) .. controls
  (50.1078,279.6723) and (48.7426,282.8163) .. (45.7530,285.9395) .. controls
  (45.0608,286.6627) and (44.6869,287.3330) .. (44.5724,288.0562) .. controls
  (44.0349,291.4502) and (42.7403,296.0276) .. (42.1217,296.7213) .. controls
  (41.7648,297.1215) and (41.1947,297.1843) .. (37.9195,297.1843) .. controls
  (34.2202,297.1843) and (34.1203,297.1693) .. (33.7174,296.5545) .. controls
  (33.3396,295.9779) and (33.3494,295.7635) .. (33.8333,294.0175) --
  (34.3617,292.1104) -- (32.9831,292.3322) .. controls (31.3480,292.5953) and
  (24.0735,292.6290) .. (22.7206,292.3798) -- (21.7743,292.2054) --
  (21.1790,294.2318) .. controls (20.2900,297.2577) and (20.4197,297.1843) ..
  (15.9591,297.1843) .. controls (12.2713,297.1843) and (12.1588,297.1676) ..
  (11.7614,296.5612) -- cycle(36.7032,282.1261) .. controls (37.1792,281.9373)
  and (37.6852,281.5650) .. (37.8277,281.2989) .. controls (37.9701,281.0327)
  and (38.0867,279.2800) .. (38.0867,277.4041) .. controls (38.0867,274.0791)
  and (38.0695,273.9771) .. (37.4036,273.3518) -- (36.7206,272.7103) --
  (26.8422,272.7103) .. controls (21.4091,272.7103) and (16.8699,272.8043) ..
  (16.7551,272.9192) .. controls (16.4775,273.1969) and (16.2807,279.3879) ..
  (16.5024,280.8666) -- (16.6772,282.0322) -- (18.3200,282.3054) .. controls
  (20.7458,282.7089) and (35.5994,282.5640) .. (36.7032,282.1262) --
  cycle(15.5779,269.7642) .. controls (16.2980,268.8487) and (16.2702,268.2000)
  .. (15.4768,267.4066) .. controls (14.2164,266.1462) and (12.4221,266.9216) ..
  (12.4221,268.7266) .. controls (12.4221,270.4142) and (14.5232,271.1050) ..
  (15.5779,269.7642) -- cycle(52.9033,266.3564) .. controls (52.9033,265.8422)
  and (51.1535,263.9210) .. (50.9083,264.1661) .. controls (50.5218,264.5526)
  and (51.0994,265.7360) .. (51.9182,266.2353) .. controls (52.9422,266.8596)
  and (52.9033,266.8548) .. (52.9033,266.3564) -- cycle(30.1883,265.2075) ..
  controls (28.4468,264.5878) and (27.6205,263.9904) .. (26.5183,262.5543) ..
  controls (25.4449,261.1557) and (25.0385,259.6658) .. (25.1760,257.6333) ..
  controls (25.3040,255.7406) and (25.9513,254.2863) .. (27.2387,252.9989) ..
  controls (28.7839,251.4537) and (29.9551,251.0145) .. (32.5304,251.0145) ..
  controls (34.4908,251.0145) and (34.9321,251.1048) .. (35.9700,251.7185) ..
  controls (38.5102,253.2205) and (39.7803,255.4241) .. (39.7581,258.2905) ..
  controls (39.7418,260.3841) and (39.2619,261.5926) .. (37.8302,263.1459) ..
  controls (35.7943,265.3546) and (32.8406,266.1515) .. (30.1883,265.2075) --
  cycle(33.1852,263.1830) .. controls (33.3344,262.8932) and (33.7790,262.3390)
  .. (34.1733,261.9513) .. controls (35.7409,260.4100) and (35.3328,258.8215) ..
  (33.0882,257.7276) .. controls (31.3987,256.9043) and (31.0221,256.3971) ..
  (31.6408,255.7784) .. controls (32.1808,255.2384) and (33.3015,255.4480) ..
  (33.8194,256.1859) .. controls (34.2616,256.8158) and (35.0590,256.8610) ..
  (35.2862,256.2689) .. controls (35.4987,255.7152) and (34.8047,254.6469) ..
  (33.9920,254.2766) .. controls (33.6471,254.1194) and (33.2920,253.7004) ..
  (33.2029,253.3454) .. controls (32.9895,252.4954) and (31.9091,252.5842) ..
  (31.7844,253.4619) .. controls (31.7379,253.7893) and (31.5837,254.0572) ..
  (31.4416,254.0572) .. controls (31.2996,254.0572) and (30.8912,254.3495) ..
  (30.5340,254.7067) .. controls (30.0660,255.1747) and (29.8846,255.6450) ..
  (29.8846,256.3904) .. controls (29.8846,257.6560) and (30.7129,258.5878) ..
  (32.2464,259.0472) .. controls (33.4580,259.4102) and (33.6899,259.6716) ..
  (33.4557,260.4096) .. controls (33.2215,261.1474) and (31.6073,261.1457) ..
  (31.1461,260.4076) .. controls (30.6598,259.6289) and (29.6200,259.7030) ..
  (29.6200,260.5164) .. controls (29.6200,261.1223) and (30.9273,262.5243) ..
  (31.4924,262.5243) .. controls (31.6267,262.5243) and (31.7367,262.7425) ..
  (31.7367,263.0093) .. controls (31.7367,263.9995) and (32.7051,264.1159) ..
  (33.1852,263.1834) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Not bad, right?

#### Edit

If you want a macro for this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\def\pig[#1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.80pt, x=0.80pt, yscale=-1.000000, xscale=1.000000, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt,#1]
\fill[yellow] (15,285) rectangle (40,270);
\path[fill=black,line width=0.056pt] (11.7614,296.5612) .. controls
  (11.3851,295.9868) and (11.4156,295.6960) .. (12.1522,292.8392) .. controls
  (12.5917,291.1347) and (12.9512,289.5263) .. (12.9512,289.2649) .. controls
  (12.9512,289.0035) and (12.4849,288.4664) .. (11.9150,288.0715) .. controls
  (10.8120,287.3071) and (8.0433,284.4949) .. (7.3902,283.4755) .. controls
  (7.1101,283.0385) and (6.6579,282.8200) .. (5.8075,282.7111) .. controls
  (2.4694,282.2834) and (0.6994,279.9432) .. (-0.0230,275.0021) .. controls
  (-0.3005,273.1045) and (-0.2866,272.7630) .. (0.0919,272.1854) .. controls
  (0.3287,271.8239) and (0.7889,271.4769) .. (1.1145,271.4143) .. controls
  (3.8064,270.8964) and (4.9406,270.6343) .. (5.2960,270.4477) .. controls
  (5.5240,270.3280) and (6.1422,269.3594) .. (6.6698,268.2952) .. controls
  (7.6356,266.3469) and (9.2936,264.3698) .. (11.2099,262.8815) --
  (12.2466,262.0763) -- (11.5545,261.1688) .. controls (10.7799,260.1533) and
  (9.3930,257.2403) .. (9.1277,256.0717) -- (8.9543,255.3080) --
  (11.5481,255.4387) .. controls (14.4665,255.5857) and (18.0645,256.6356) ..
  (20.6242,258.0870) .. controls (21.4245,258.5408) and (22.3934,258.8904) ..
  (22.7772,258.8640) .. controls (23.3875,258.8219) and (23.4979,258.9405) ..
  (23.6580,259.8100) .. controls (24.1689,262.5854) and (26.2258,265.1720) ..
  (28.8628,266.3555) .. controls (30.7667,267.2099) and (33.5066,267.3323) ..
  (35.4030,266.6477) .. controls (37.0986,266.0356) and (38.9808,264.5459) ..
  (39.9326,263.0626) -- (40.7698,261.7580) -- (42.1396,262.6008) .. controls
  (44.0447,263.7731) and (47.0598,266.7080) .. (48.0085,268.3137) .. controls
  (48.4853,269.1206) and (48.9906,269.6592) .. (49.2738,269.6624) .. controls
  (49.9018,269.6694) and (51.5831,268.9567) .. (51.5702,268.6889) .. controls
  (51.5642,268.5724) and (51.1821,268.2389) .. (50.7202,267.9478) .. controls
  (49.4649,267.1569) and (48.6700,265.8172) .. (48.6700,264.4926) .. controls
  (48.6700,263.5579) and (48.8094,263.2473) .. (49.4840,262.6797) .. controls
  (49.9318,262.3030) and (50.5925,261.9947) .. (50.9524,261.9947) .. controls
  (52.5243,261.9947) and (54.2980,263.6473) .. (54.8197,265.5981) .. controls
  (54.9902,266.2356) and (55.2833,266.7572) .. (55.4710,266.7572) .. controls
  (55.6587,266.7572) and (56.2840,266.3310) .. (56.8607,265.8100) .. controls
  (57.9885,264.7911) and (58.8201,264.7508) .. (59.1215,265.7003) .. controls
  (59.4670,266.7891) and (57.3965,268.5769) .. (55.2846,269.0134) .. controls
  (54.7753,269.1186) and (53.9204,269.5987) .. (53.3849,270.0802) .. controls
  (52.8495,270.5616) and (51.8046,271.1711) .. (51.0630,271.4345) .. controls
  (49.7563,271.8986) and (49.7210,271.9379) .. (49.9199,272.7087) .. controls
  (50.0328,273.1462) and (50.1222,274.5756) .. (50.1185,275.8853) .. controls
  (50.1078,279.6723) and (48.7426,282.8163) .. (45.7530,285.9395) .. controls
  (45.0608,286.6627) and (44.6869,287.3330) .. (44.5724,288.0562) .. controls
  (44.0349,291.4502) and (42.7403,296.0276) .. (42.1217,296.7213) .. controls
  (41.7648,297.1215) and (41.1947,297.1843) .. (37.9195,297.1843) .. controls
  (34.2202,297.1843) and (34.1203,297.1693) .. (33.7174,296.5545) .. controls
  (33.3396,295.9779) and (33.3494,295.7635) .. (33.8333,294.0175) --
  (34.3617,292.1104) -- (32.9831,292.3322) .. controls (31.3480,292.5953) and
  (24.0735,292.6290) .. (22.7206,292.3798) -- (21.7743,292.2054) --
  (21.1790,294.2318) .. controls (20.2900,297.2577) and (20.4197,297.1843) ..
  (15.9591,297.1843) .. controls (12.2713,297.1843) and (12.1588,297.1676) ..
  (11.7614,296.5612) -- cycle(36.7032,282.1261) .. controls (37.1792,281.9373)
  and (37.6852,281.5650) .. (37.8277,281.2989) .. controls (37.9701,281.0327)
  and (38.0867,279.2800) .. (38.0867,277.4041) .. controls (38.0867,274.0791)
  and (38.0695,273.9771) .. (37.4036,273.3518) -- (36.7206,272.7103) --
  (26.8422,272.7103) .. controls (21.4091,272.7103) and (16.8699,272.8043) ..
  (16.7551,272.9192) .. controls (16.4775,273.1969) and (16.2807,279.3879) ..
  (16.5024,280.8666) -- (16.6772,282.0322) -- (18.3200,282.3054) .. controls
  (20.7458,282.7089) and (35.5994,282.5640) .. (36.7032,282.1262) --
  cycle(15.5779,269.7642) .. controls (16.2980,268.8487) and (16.2702,268.2000)
  .. (15.4768,267.4066) .. controls (14.2164,266.1462) and (12.4221,266.9216) ..
  (12.4221,268.7266) .. controls (12.4221,270.4142) and (14.5232,271.1050) ..
  (15.5779,269.7642) -- cycle(52.9033,266.3564) .. controls (52.9033,265.8422)
  and (51.1535,263.9210) .. (50.9083,264.1661) .. controls (50.5218,264.5526)
  and (51.0994,265.7360) .. (51.9182,266.2353) .. controls (52.9422,266.8596)
  and (52.9033,266.8548) .. (52.9033,266.3564) -- cycle(30.1883,265.2075) ..
  controls (28.4468,264.5878) and (27.6205,263.9904) .. (26.5183,262.5543) ..
  controls (25.4449,261.1557) and (25.0385,259.6658) .. (25.1760,257.6333) ..
  controls (25.3040,255.7406) and (25.9513,254.2863) .. (27.2387,252.9989) ..
  controls (28.7839,251.4537) and (29.9551,251.0145) .. (32.5304,251.0145) ..
  controls (34.4908,251.0145) and (34.9321,251.1048) .. (35.9700,251.7185) ..
  controls (38.5102,253.2205) and (39.7803,255.4241) .. (39.7581,258.2905) ..
  controls (39.7418,260.3841) and (39.2619,261.5926) .. (37.8302,263.1459) ..
  controls (35.7943,265.3546) and (32.8406,266.1515) .. (30.1883,265.2075) --
  cycle(33.1852,263.1830) .. controls (33.3344,262.8932) and (33.7790,262.3390)
  .. (34.1733,261.9513) .. controls (35.7409,260.4100) and (35.3328,258.8215) ..
  (33.0882,257.7276) .. controls (31.3987,256.9043) and (31.0221,256.3971) ..
  (31.6408,255.7784) .. controls (32.1808,255.2384) and (33.3015,255.4480) ..
  (33.8194,256.1859) .. controls (34.2616,256.8158) and (35.0590,256.8610) ..
  (35.2862,256.2689) .. controls (35.4987,255.7152) and (34.8047,254.6469) ..
  (33.9920,254.2766) .. controls (33.6471,254.1194) and (33.2920,253.7004) ..
  (33.2029,253.3454) .. controls (32.9895,252.4954) and (31.9091,252.5842) ..
  (31.7844,253.4619) .. controls (31.7379,253.7893) and (31.5837,254.0572) ..
  (31.4416,254.0572) .. controls (31.2996,254.0572) and (30.8912,254.3495) ..
  (30.5340,254.7067) .. controls (30.0660,255.1747) and (29.8846,255.6450) ..
  (29.8846,256.3904) .. controls (29.8846,257.6560) and (30.7129,258.5878) ..
  (32.2464,259.0472) .. controls (33.4580,259.4102) and (33.6899,259.6716) ..
  (33.4557,260.4096) .. controls (33.2215,261.1474) and (31.6073,261.1457) ..
  (31.1461,260.4076) .. controls (30.6598,259.6289) and (29.6200,259.7030) ..
  (29.6200,260.5164) .. controls (29.6200,261.1223) and (30.9273,262.5243) ..
  (31.4924,262.5243) .. controls (31.6267,262.5243) and (31.7367,262.7425) ..
  (31.7367,263.0093) .. controls (31.7367,263.9995) and (32.7051,264.1159) ..
  (33.1852,263.1834) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
\pig[scale=2] \pig[scale=0.5]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Absolutely perfect pigs year of a fun answer to the cut and paste question, perhaps you could migrate it there :-) https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/473287/welcoming-2019-lunar-new-year-how-to-draw-a-lovely-pig?r=SearchResults&s=1|65.9625

Comment: @KJO Oh why I did not think of that :) A new answer to the pig question <s>will be present in a couple of minutes :)</s> is now posted!

Comment: @JouleV can you comment in your code where i can edit/bigger (width/height) of yellow area? Thanks

Comment: @tisaigon Unfortunately editing the yellow area is extremely difficult because it depends on the `\path` commands, not the custom-added `\fill` command. I'm afraid I can't do it for you. You know, the `\path` commands are generated by a professor, so only the professor can understand ;-)